# How to get the count on virtual relationships in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I made a virtual relationship with the **"count: true"** option, but the count doesn't match with the array length.

There is a "developers" list in a "team" and they have two virtual fields related with "tickets":

- "tickets" (with the full array of its tickets)
- "ticketsCount" (with the count of its tickets).

#### Code ready to run (mongoose 5.6.7)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://@127.0.0.1:27017/test-virtual-count', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const DeveloperSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
}, { toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } });

const TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    developers: [DeveloperSchema]
});

const TicketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    assigned: String,
    description: String
});

DeveloperSchema.virtual('tickets', {
    ref: 'Ticket',
    localField: 'name',
    foreignField: 'assigned',
  });

DeveloperSchema.virtual('ticketsCount', {
    ref: 'Ticket',
    localField: 'name',
    foreignField: 'assigned',
    count: true
});

const Ticket = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);
const Team = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);

const run = async () => {

    await new Team({
        name: 'Rocket',
        developers: [
            {
                name: 'John'
            },
            {
                name: 'Mike'
            },
            {
                name: 'Ignacio'
            }
        ]
    }).save();

    await Ticket.insertMany([
        {
            assigned: 'Mike',
            description: 'Build a Demo'
        },
        {
            assigned: 'Mike',
            description: 'Rollback'
        },
        {
            assigned: 'John',
            description: 'Refactor'
        },
        {
            assigned: 'Mike',
            description: 'Tests'
        },
        {
            assigned: 'Mike',
            description: 'HotFix'
        }
    ]);

    const team = await Team.findOne({}, {_id: 0,__v:0}).populate('developers.tickets', {_id: 0,__v:0}).populate('developers.ticketsCount');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(team, null, 2));
};

run();
```

#### Output

The **tickets** array is almost perfect (except for the developer who doesn't have tickets...) but the **tickesCount** doesn't match with de **tickets.length**, it's **equal to the number of developers**.

```
{
    "name": "Rocket",
    "developers": [
      {
        "_id": "5d3f146ffd04097b0cd10532",
        "name": "John",
        "id": "5d3f146ffd04097b0cd10532",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "assigned": "John",
            "description": "Refactor"
          }
        ],
        "ticketsCount": 3
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d3f146ffd04097b0cd10531",
        "name": "Mike",
        "id": "5d3f146ffd04097b0cd10531",
        "tickets": [
          {
            "assigned": "Mike",
            "description": "Build a Demo"
          },
          {
            "assigned": "Mike",
            "description": "Rollback"
          },
          {
            "assigned": "Mike",
            "description": "Tests"
          },
          {
            "assigned": "Mike",
            "description": "HotFix"
          }
        ],
        "ticketsCount": 3
      },
      {
        "_id": "5d3f146ffd04097b0cd10530",
        "name": "Ignacio",
        "id": "5d3f146ffd04097b0cd10530",
        "tickets": [
          "Ignacio"
        ],
        "ticketsCount": 3
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: confirmed bug: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7573

Comment: fixed on 5.6.9: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/commit/dc2e87cdfbf106630abf31362bd03318e74a616e